# ActionScript 3.0 - reading each MXML element

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

**If there is already a post for this, I'm sorry but I could not find it.**

I have the following form (sample):

```
<mx:Label x="105.5" y="0" text="Cadastramento Basico" fontSize="22"/>
<mx:Text x="140" y="42" text="Nome:"/>
<mx:TextInput x="176" y="40" id="nome"/>
<mx:Text x="138" y="74" text="E-mail:"/>
<mx:TextInput x="177" y="72" id="email"/>
<mx:Text x="125" y="105" text="Telefone:"/>
<mx:TextInput x="177" y="103" restrict="012456789" id="telefone"/>
```

And I need to read each element in ActionScript to clean up every one after a user has clicked on a submit button. In jQuery we have the function `elements.each()`, I just need something like this.

How can I do this please?

Comment: It would be a much cleaner approach to bind the values of those fields to a data model and then iterate over that model's properties to reset them. You should avoid interacting directly with view components.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Please make sure you [read the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e53.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62f1b-7fdd) before asking questions:
2. You should wrap your form into a `<mx:Form>` tag:

   ```
   <mx:Form id="myForm" label="Cadastramento Basico">
       <mx:FormItem label="Nome:" >
           <<mx:TextInput id="nome"/>
       </mx:FormItem>
       <mx:FormItem label="E-mail:" >
           <<mx:TextInput id="mail"/>
       </mx:FormItem>            
       <mx:FormItem label="Telefone:" >
           <<mx:TextInput id="telefone" restrict="012456789"/>
       </mx:FormItem>
   </mx:Form>
   ```
3. Then do it manually by running through all items of the form and check if they have the proper type and a valid property to be reset (add them to the code below if necessary).

   ```
   private function clearForm():void
   {
        for each(var o:* in loginForm.getChildren() ){
            if(o is FormItem){
                var item:FormItem = o as FormItem;
                for each(var o2:Object in item.getChildren()){
                    if(o2.hasOwnProperty("text")) {
                        o2.text = "";
                    }
                }
             }
        }
   }
   ```

Comment: -1.  Although this is a valid approach; a form is a layout container; using it is not necessary or required in order to process the UI elements.  I much prefer @riastar's recommended approach.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Using the form container lays out the items easily. But true, the 3rd point is not the fastest approach. Changing the model would be much faster. +1